# How to filter objects in ManyToMany field back reference?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I want to list all published tags and published posts like this:

```
Tag1
├── first-post
└── second-post
Tag2
├── third-post
└── fourth-post
```

I have `Tag` and `Post` models like this:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=192)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='posts')    
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

I have a context processor which is passing tags to templates:

```
def tags(request):
    published_tags = Tag.objects\
        .filter(is_published=True)\
        .exclude(posts=None)\
        .order_by('name')
    return {'tags': published_tags}
```

I'm listing Tags and Posts in template like this:

```
{% for tag in tags %}
    <h1>{{ tag.name }}</h1>
    {% for post in tag.posts.all %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I can filter tags by `is_published`. How I can filter the `posts` by `is_published` within back reference in the Tags (`Tag.posts`)?

I don't want to return two query sets named `tags` and `posts'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
def tags(request):
    published_tags = Tag.objects\
        .filter(is_published=True, posts__is_published=True)\
        .exclude(posts=None)\
        .order_by('name')\
        .distinct()
    return {'tags': published_tags}
```

ps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging